# bisonc++ inheritance with polymorphic

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, bisonc++

I'm trying to construct an AST from a bison grammar. Bison generates the parser correctly but when I try to parse an example code with some math operations the following error its printed:

```
[Fatal] calling `.get<Tag__::EXPR>()', but Tag INT is encountered.
```

After debugging I notice that the issue is in the `expr` non-terminal with the following production:

```
expr:
      ...
    | operator
      {
         $$ = $1;
      }
```

And `operator` has the following production itself:

```
operator:
   ...
| INTEGER
  {
    $$ = new ast::expression::IntASTNode(std::stoi(d_scanner.matched()));
  }
```

I'm using polymorphic semantic types, `expr` and `operator` are tagged with `EXPR` that respond to `ExprASTNode` type witch is the base class for `IntASTNode` with the tag `INT`. I'm guessing that bison is getting the type from the tag and checking the tags before making any cast. Is there any way that I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you substitute the assignment by this:

```
operator:
     ...
        | INTEGER
          {
            $$(ast::expression::IntASTNode(std::stoi(d_scanner.matched())));
          }
```

then `bisonc++` makes a `static_cast` between the the `$$`'s semantic value and the one from the `$$(expr)`. Further information in the [bisonc++ manual](http://bisoncpp.sourceforge.net/bisonc++05.html#ACTIONS).